# HTML5 tags: how to use them correctly?

Tags: seo, html, wordpress, html5, semantic-web

I want the best possible **SEO** for my WordPress site. To do this, I made enhancements and used HTML5. The problem is that I don't know how to use particular tags. For instance, I have an article tag in a `<section>` tag. Is this good or not? Let me show you my snippet, than you can see it better...

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<nav id="menu">
<aside class="containing-links-to-posts">
<section id="content-section">
<div id="widgets">
</div>
```

Explained:

`<aside class="containing-links-to-posts>` = **left widget**

`<div id="widgets">` = **right widget**

`<nav id="menu">` = **navigation menu**

`<section id="content-section">` = **the main section with the posts and comments in it**

**In `<aside>`, I got this:**

```
<section id="index">
<nav id="partial-index">
<div class="widget-title">Today's posts</div>
<ul class="blabla">
<li>
Post name
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</section>
```

Question: is this good? I am asking you this because I already had a nav and and a section (see above). I am afraid that using these tags too much will cause problems.

And last but not least, I have this in `<section id="content-section">`:

```
<section id="content-section">
<ol>
<li>
<article>
<header>
<h1>
<a>testttt</a>
</h1>
</header>
<div class="content">
<div>
<span class="favorites">
</div>
<footer class="post-meta">
<div class="info">
<a class="entry-id">#32474</a>
<time class="timestamp" datetime="19-04-2013">19.04.2013 13:18</time>
<span class="author vcard">
<a class="url" rel="author">testauthor</a>
</span>
</div>
</footer>
<span class="tags">
<img alt="tags" src="">
<span>
<a rel="tag" href="">test</a>
</span>
</span>
</article>
</li>
</ol>
```

I think this is too much to put in an `<article>` tag, or not? The `<article>` tag is intended to get the POST CONTENT of a post... So that Google knows that that part is the content of an article.

I would appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, none of the major search engines have made any definite proclamations on HTML5 as it pertains to SEO. As a result, beyond the usual good practice of well-formed, semantically correct code, we can do little more than speculate on that front.

For advice on writing well-formed and semantically correct HTML5, I strongly recommend referring to the [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com) blog. The contributors are people who work on the HTML specification and give very detailed, real world applications of new elements and attributes.

To briefly answer some of your questions, `<article>` should be a free-standing piece of content; something that could be removed from the context of your webpage and still make sense. It's fine to have `<article>` within a `<section>`, however the precise detail of when to use `<section>` instead of something else is quite involved, so I recommend reading [HTML5 Doctor's article on that subject](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/).

`<nav>` can be used multiple times in a page if that page has multiple, substantial navigational segments. So it'd be fine to have main navigation, a sidebar navigation, etc. encoded in `<nav>`s.

One thing to bear in mind is that HTML5 is still developing. `<hgroup>`, for example, has has already been retired, so you need to keep an eye on how the specification evolves.

Comment: Hmm, thanks Gdav, this is a nice answer. If there is nothing wrong with my own code, I will keep it that way. Of course I will look on to your links, which will be helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would add is that Google does recognize the author tags. 
Doing a quick Google search - this looks like a good article to read:
http://www.copyblogger.com/wordpress-google-authorship/

Also, use responsive templates - one url for desktop and mobile.

Comment: Re: author tags - not anymore. Authorship has been retired for good, it seems: http://searchengineland.com/google-stop-using-authorship-completely-even-indepth-articles-252480